# Why return is required while defining my module using requirejs?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

Following is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Using Require js for modular loading of scripts.</title>
    <!--Requirejs first loads the module that is specified in data-main .. So it will load the module init,init has two dependencies first is knockout so it loads the knockout first, then myAppViewModel next -->
    <script type="text/javascript" data-main="scripts/init.js" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Name : <span data-bind="text: myName"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

init.js

```
require(['knockout-3.2.0', 'myAppViewModel'], function(ko, myAppViewModel) {
    ko.applyBindings(myAppViewModel());
});
```

myAppViewModel.js

```
define(function () {
    return function myAppViewModel() {
        this.myName = 'Sudheer';
    };
});
```

If i remove return in above function. It says myAppViewModel() is not a constructor. Why return is needed in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Require js calls the function that you pass to `define()` in order to obtain an instance of your module. So whatever you return from that outer function is what it gets as your module.

If you remove the `return` from your code there, the outer function returns nothing, and therefore the value that Require js obtains for your module is `undefined`.

So that's why you need a return statement.

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#funcmodule

Comment: Thanq JLRishe :) i got the context. Require assigns the return value of define function to myAppViewModel. According to knockout a module is a function so define function should return a function. If i remove return undefined is returned. So it says undefined is not a function.